# Behavior of optim() function in R

Tags: r, optimization

I'm doing maximum likelihood estimation using the R `optim` function.

The command I used is

```
optim(3, func, lower=1.0001, method="L-BFGS-B")$par
```

The function `func` has infinite value if the parameter is 1. 
Thus I set the lower value to be 1.0001.
But sometime an error occurs.

```
Error in optim(3, func, lower = 1.0001, method = "L-BFGS-B", sx = sx,  : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

What happened next is hard to understand.
If I run the same command again, then it gives the result 1.0001 which is lower limit.
It seems that the `optim` function 'learns' that 1 is not the proper answer. 
How can the `optim` function can give the answer 1.0001 at my first run?

P.S.
I just found that this problem occurs only in stand-alone R-console. If I run the same code in R Studio, it does not occur. Very strange.

Comment: it would be much easier if you gave a reproducible example.  It's weird, but not impossible, that you get different results in RStudio.  One thing you should keep in mind is that by default `optim` uses a stepsize of 0.001 for computing finite-difference approximations to the local gradient; that *shouldn't* (in principle) cause this problem, but it might.  What happens if you use `control=list(ndeps=5e-4)` to make sure the finite-difference step is smaller than the distance between your `lower` value and your hard boundary.

Comment: You might also instrument your `func` function to print (or `cat()`) the values it is actually called with, to document precisely what `optim()` is evaluating.

Comment: PS results of `sessionInfo()` would also be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method "L-BFGS-B" requires all computed values of the function to be finite.
It seems, for some reason, that optim is evaluating your function at the value of 1.0, giving you an inf, then throwing an error.

If you want a quick hack, try defining a new function that gives a very high value(or low if you're trying to maximize) for inputs of 1.

```
func2 <- function(x){
  if (x == 1){
    return -9999
  }
  else{
    return func(x)
  }
}

optim(3, func2, lower=1.0001, method="L-BFGS-B")$par
```

Answer (score 0):

(Posted as answer rather than comment for now; will delete later if appropriate.)
For what it's worth, I can't get this example (with a singularity at 1) to fail, even using the default control parameters (e.g. `ndeps=1e-3`):

```
func <- function(x) 1/(x-1)*x^2
library(numDeriv)
grad(func,x=2)  ## critical point at x=2
optim(par=1+1e-4,fn=func,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=1+1e-4)
```

Try a wide range of starting values:

```
svec <- 1+10^(seq(-4,2,by=0.5))
sapply(svec,optim,fn=func,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=1+1e-4)
```

These all work.