# R: How to specify a gradient function for use in optim() with one customized function while leave the other finite-difference approximation

Tags: r, optimization, gradient

What I need is a gradient function

```
f_gradient <- function(u, data) {
a <- u[1]
b <- u[1]
c(exp(data,a), fin-diff-approx(data,b))
}
```

Here fin-diff-approx should be as default used if gr is Null
 
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html

I tried looking many places like 
[how to propery specify a gradient function for use in optim() or other optimizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622956/how-to-propery-specify-a-gradient-function-for-use-in-optim-or-other-optimizer) 
[Behavior of optim() function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385911/behavior-of-optim-function-in-r)

There is a numDeriv support in optimx
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-August/288541.html 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optimx/optimx.pdf

but none of them seems referred how can I only special one gradient function for training of two parameters. Really appreciate any help and discussion